# Many-body relativistic classical Hamiltonian

Tags: special-relativity, hamiltonian, many-body

All classical mechanics textbooks I know only discuss the one-body Hamiltonian in an external field

$$H = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + c^2(\mathbf{p}-e\mathbf{A}/c)^2} + e\phi$$

Jackson in his celebrated textbook on electrodynamics also gives this one-body Hamiltonian and then claims it is not possible to formulate a fully relativistic theory for interacting particles. He only provides an approximate two-body Lagrangian, valid up to order $(v/c)^2$, which can be used to derive the following two-body Hamiltonian, valid up to the same order,

$$H=\left(1-{1 \over 4}{p_{1}^{2} \over m_{1}^{2}c^{2}}\right){p_{1}^{2} \over 2m_{1}}+\left(1-{1 \over 4}{p_{2}^{2} \over m_{2}^{2}c^{2}}\right){p_{2}^{2} \over 2m_{2}}+{e_{1}e_{2} \over r} \left(1 - {1 \over 2m_{1}m_{2}c^{2}}{\mathbf  p}_{1}\cdot \left[{\mathbf  1}+{\mathbf  {{\hat  r}}}{\mathbf  {{\hat  r}}}\right]\cdot {\mathbf  p}_{2}\right)$$

This is the so-called Darwin Hamiltonian. H. M. Quiney writes [1] that

> it is not possible to construct a classical, relativistic Hamiltonian theory for the rest energy of $N$ interacting particles, which is fully Lorentz-invariant through all orders in $(v/c)$.

He then simply writes the Darwin Hamiltonian. Both Jackson and Quiney identify the difficulties in the parts of the Hamiltonian (Lagragian) describing electromagnetic interactions.

However, in the opposite side, R. Hakim [2] mentions the following many-body Hamiltonian

$$H = \sum_i \sqrt{m_i^2c^4 + c^2(\mathbf{p}_i-e\mathbf{A}/c)^2} + \frac{1}{8\pi}\int d^3x \; (\mathbf{E}^2+\mathbf{B}^2)$$

and the claims it has been used by a number of authors (I don't have access to any of those works). His claim is perplexing me, because I don't see how this Hamiltonian can be made consistent unless the vector potential only includes an external field and not the internal interactions of the particles in the many-body system. If this was not weird enough, Hakim mentions the no-interaction theorem of Currie, Jordan, and Sudarshan in the same page where he writes the above Hamiltonian.

Hanno Essén [3] writes a similar Hamiltonian as that of above, but considering both external and internal contributions separately $(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}_i)$ and with a simplified expression (radiationless) for the field term. To add further confusion, Essén claims his expression is exact (in the absence of radiation)

> So far no approximations have been made in the derivation of the Hamiltonian from the Darwin Lagrangian.

where his 'Darwin Lagrangian' is not what everyone else considers but the next mixture

$$\sum_iL_i - \sum_{i} \sum_{i<j} \frac{e_ie_j}{r_{ij}} - V_D$$

where $V_D$ is the Darwin interaction and the $L_i$ are fully relativistic one-body Lagrangians in external fields

$$L_i = m_ic^2 \sqrt{1 - \frac{v_i^2}{c^2}} - e_i \phi + e_i \frac{\mathbf{v}_i}{c}\mathbf{A}$$

Since the literature I know is contradictory (and some looks incorrect to me), my question is which is the relativistic classical Hamiltonian for a many-body system of charged particles, *if it even exists*?

REFERENCES:

[1] Chapter 33 of the Handbook of Molecular Physics and Quantum Chemistry (Wiley; 2003).

[2] Introduction to Relativistic Statistical Mechanics, Classical and Quantum (World Scientific; 2011).

[3] Darwin magnetic interaction energy and its macroscopic consequences. Phys. Rev. E 53, 5228 (1996).

Comment: One point: If the Hamiltonian includes a field, it is no longer a Hamiltonian of particle-particle interactions. ie, instead of 6N-dimensional phase space, you now have infinite dimensional phase space even for the case $N=2$, and so it's not really an "N-particle hamiltonian". So Hakim is not contradicting himself.

Comment: Would this reference be useful?  The Relativistic N-body Problem
in a Separable Two-Body Basis [https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/0010003]